# Intersection with a set doesn't affect indexation of indexed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If we have three sets $A,B,C \subset\Omega$ and we take the intersection with another set $Y$, we have $3$ sets i.e. $A\cap Y,B\cap Y$ and $C\cap Y$

My question is how can we prove that the intersection with a set doesn't affect the indexation of the initial set (here we have $3$ initial sets) ?

More formally if we take $E_\alpha\in Image(\mathscr P(\Omega) ^{E})$ where $E$ is finite, infinite, or infinite uncountable, how can we know that $\{E_\alpha \cap Y\}_{\alpha \in E}$ has the same cardinality (I'm not sure if it's the correct word) as $\{E_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in E}$ ?

Comment: To start with... supposing $A=\{1\},B=\{2\},C=\{3\}$ and $Y=\{4\}$, you would have $\{A,B,C\}$ has three elements, but $\{A\cap Y,B\cap Y,C\cap Y\}=\{\emptyset\}$ has one element... so surely you aren't talking about this as though it were a set or collection... Perhaps you mean to talk about this as a sequence and ask why there are as many elements in the sequence before and after?  For that, consider what it means to be a sequence (*as defined using functions*) and compare the domains.

Comment: Clearly, the domain of $f~:~[3]\to \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ which maps $1\mapsto A, 2\mapsto B, 3\mapsto C$ has the same domain as $g~:~[3]\to \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ which maps $1\mapsto A\cap Y, 2\mapsto B\cap Y, 3\mapsto C\cap Y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that might not be a bijection since the outputs could repeat, as with my first comment's example.  What matters here is that the domains are the same, i.e. the indexing set is the same... but by the very nature of how they defined the sequences, of course they have the same index.